# Using MDX Parameters in Report Builder 2.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameters, mdx, reportbuilder

I currently have a query that looks like this:

`SELECT`
  `NON EMPTY ([Measures].[TOTAL]) ON 0,`
  `NON EMPTY (([ENROLL DATE].[CALENDAR].[YEAR].["` **`+ Parameters!EnrollDate.Value +`** `"] * [DIM ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT PROG].ALLMEMBERS)) ON 1`

`FROM (SELECT (([DIM ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT].[TERMINATION REASON].[Still Enrolled])) ON  0     FROM [NapaCHI]);`

The **bold** section comes from the parameters section where I manually specified the parameters with `Label = 2006 and Value = 2006`. I have tried just about every acceptable syntax and read about every article about this and cannot seem to get it to work whether I define the values myself or use a separate MDX statement that selects distinct non-empty years and (NULL) for the aggregate.

Help please, it's driving me insane!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression looks incomplete, you would need to start it with and = sign and quote it propertly. Something like the following

```
="SELECT
NON EMPTY ([Measures].[TOTAL]) ON 0, 
NON EMPTY (([ENROLL DATE].[CALENDAR].[YEAR].[" + Parameters!EnrollDate.Value + "] * [DIM ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT PROG].ALLMEMBERS)) ON 1 

FROM (SELECT (([DIM ENROLLMENT].[ENROLLMENT].[TERMINATION REASON].[Still Enrolled])) ON 0 FROM [NapaCHI]);"
```

You may also have issues with datatypes, you might want to either use the .Label property of the parameter or explicitly convert the value to a string. If none of this works it would be helpful to know what error you are getting.

Comment: I actually don't get any error, the query just doesn't return anything. I think you may be on the right track with the datatypes though but I'm not sure what it would be expecting there.

Comment: It could be data types then. If your parameter passes in a full date, then it could expand to [Enroll Date].[Calendar].[Year].[01-01-2009] instead of semething like [Enroll Date].[Calendar].[Year].[2009] and this would result in an empty row axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think this MDX is requiring:

```
NON EMPTY (([ENROLL DATE].[CALENDAR].[YEAR].[Calendar " + Parameters!EnrollDate.Value + "]
```

Or you could you the actual MDX language like so:

```
[ENROLL DATE].[CALENDAR].[YEAR].&[" + Parameters!EnrollDate.Value + "-01-01T00:00:00]
```

Either of those should work.